# One IdentityServer for many APIs

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an IdentiyServer project with this config:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API 1"),
            new ApiResource("api2", "My API 2"),
            new ApiResource("api3", "My API 3"),
            new ApiResource("api4", "My API 4")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId          = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,    // no interactive user, use the client id/secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets     = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())}, // secret for authentication
                AllowedScopes     = {"api1"}                         // scopes that client has access to
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId          = "client-da-focus",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets     = {new Secret("secret-da-focus".Sha256())},
                AllowedScopes     = {"api2", "api3"}
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId          = "client-da-carpark",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets     = {new Secret("secret-da-carpark".Sha256())},
                AllowedScopes     = {"api4"}
            }
        };
}
```

Here is the startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                              .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                              .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
}
```

I have another API project that has an Identity controller. Here the Startup first:

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = Configuration["identity:discovery:document"];
                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidateIssuer = true,
                         ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                         {
                             "api1",
                             "api2",
                             "api3",
                             "api4"
                         }
                     };
                 });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() => new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
}
```

Now, I'm assuming that since all four `ValidAudience` are added and any client calling the identity controller API, I'de get and OK.

**I get a 401 instead.**

My third project that is the Client is setup as follow:

App.cs:

```
public class App
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;
    private readonly ILogger<App>       _logger;

    public App(IConfigurationRoot config, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<App>();
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        var appConfig = _config.GetSection("identity").Get<Identity>();

        // discover endpoints from metadata
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(appConfig.Discovery.Document);
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Discovery Error: {disco.Error}");
            return;
        }

        // request token
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
                                new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
                                {
                                    Address      = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                                    ClientId     = appConfig.Token.Request.ClientId,
                                    ClientSecret = appConfig.Token.Request.ClientSecret,
                                    Scope        = appConfig.Token.Request.Scope
                                });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Token Error: {tokenResponse.Error}");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        // call api
        var apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var response = await apiClient.GetAsync(appConfig.Api.Url);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"Api Response: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have the URLs set up properly in settings:

```
{
  "identity": {
    "discovery": {
      "document": "https://localhost:44377"
    },
    "token": {
      "request": {
        "clientId": "client-da-focus",
        "clientSecret": "secret-da-focus",
        "scope": "api2"
      }
    },
    "api": {
      "url": "https://localhost:44380/identity"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Note that I'm going for a particular API (#2) only.

When App.cs tries to `var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(appConfig.Discovery.Document);`, it just stays there indefinitely. After debugging, I noticed there was a 401.

Why is IdentityServer4 server not authorizing the API call?

Comment: How have you defined your APIResources? Please add that to your question.

Comment: @ToreNestenius The resources are defined as `new ApiResource("api1", "My API 1")` at the very top

Comment: Getting the discovery document should always work if your IdentityServer is up and running. It's an unprotected page. Are you sure the URL to IdentityServer is correct? and have you checked the traffic using [https://www.telerik.com/fiddler](Fiddler)? Also do check in the debugger that the URL here is correct appConfig.Discovery.Document.